# Apache CXF client issue with calling SSL service

Tags: java, ssl, cxf

I am trying to write a WS client using Apache CXF framework.
Remote WS has SSL security. I have yydats-keys.jks Java KeyStore with all necessary certificates for this remote WS.
Using browser (FF, Chrome) (When I import necessary keys) I can access WSDL definition.
Using SoapUI (With setting SSL keystore ti yydats-keys.jks) I can access these WS and also execute them.
Based on WSDL definition using wsdl2java I have generated starting point for implementing my client call.
Notice. This is command I use: ./wsdl2java.sh -p org.yydats -d /home/john -exsh false -dns true -dex true -verbose /home/john/yydats.wsdl

Here is WSDL (little bit modified for hiding real URLs):

```
  <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
            xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
            xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
            xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
            xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
            xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
            xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            xmlns:i0="http://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            name="StatusService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="basicBinding_policy">
      <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:TransportToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="true"/>
        </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:TransportToken>
          <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:Basic256/>
        </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          <sp:Layout>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:Strict/>
        </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:Layout>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:TransportBinding>
    </wsp:All>
      </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://ws.yydats.org/services/IndigentStatusService" location="https://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
    <wsdl:types/>
    <wsdl:binding name="basicBinding" type="i0:IIndigentStatusService">
      <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#basicBinding_policy"/>
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="Check">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.yydats.org/services/Check" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault">
      <soap:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="SurveyCheck">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.yydats.org/services/SurveyCheck" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault">
      <soap:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="ServicesCheck">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.yydats.org/services/ServicesCheck" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault">
      <soap:fault name="AddressAccessDeniedExceptionFault" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="IndigentStatusService">
      <wsdl:port name="basicBinding" binding="tns:basicBinding">
    <soap:address location="https://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc"/>
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

I have issue setting up client so it would use yydats-keys.jks. I have tried two approaches:
1) Setting JVM System Keystore and TrustStore properties:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/john/yydats-keys.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump","true");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/home/john/yydats-keys.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");

    QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "StatusService");
    StatusService ss = new StatusService(new URL("file:///home/john/yydats.wsdl"), SERVICE_NAME);
    IStatusService port = ss.getBasicBinding();
    port.surveyCheck();
  }
```

2) Setting a HTTPConduit (based on: http://aruld.info/programming-ssl-for-jetty-based-cxf-services/):

```
  private static void configureSSLOnTheClient(Object c) {
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(c);
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    try {
      TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
      tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);

      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      String trustpass = "changeit";

      File truststore = new File("/home/john/yydats-keys.jks");
      keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
      TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      trustFactory.init(keyStore);
      TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
      tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);

      truststore = new File("/home/john/yydats-keys.jks");
      keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
      KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      keyFactory.init(keyStore, trustpass.toCharArray());
      KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
      tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km);

      FiltersType filter = new FiltersType();
      filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT_.*");
      filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT1024_.*");
      filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_DES_.*");
      filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_NULL_.*");
      filter.getExclude().add(".*_DH_anon_.*");
      tlsParams.setCipherSuitesFilter(filter);

      httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
    } catch (KeyStoreException kse) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + kse.getCause());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + nsa.getCause());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + fnfe.getCause());
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException uke) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + uke.getCause());
    } catch (CertificateException ce) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + ce.getCause());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + gse.getCause());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + ioe.getCause());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
    QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "StatusService");
    StatusService ss = new StatusService(new URL("file:///home/john/yydats.wsdl"), SERVICE_NAME);
    IStatusService port = ss.getBasicBinding();

    configureSSLOnTheClient(port);

    port.surveyCheck();
  }
```

This is stack trace that I am getting:

```
  ---------------------------
  ID: 1
  Address: https://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc
  Encoding: UTF-8
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["http://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc/ServicesCheck"]}
  Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><ServicesCheck xmlns="http://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns3="yydats://yydats.Status" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel"><personCode></personCode><userName></userName><userSecondName></userSecondName><userPersonCode></userPersonCode><outErrText></outErrText><outPersCode></outPersCode></ServicesCheck></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
  --------------------------------------
  Dec 06, 2011 5:57:29 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
  WARNING: Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}StatusService#{http://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService}ServicesCheck has thrown exception, unwinding now
  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
      at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
      at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
      at $Proxy37.servicesCheck(Unknown Source)
      at lv.lattelecom.npais.sopa.IIndigentStatusService_BasicBinding_Client.main(IIndigentStatusService_BasicBinding_Client.java:170)
  Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.UntrustedURLConnectionIOException: UntrustedURLConnectionIOException invoking https://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc: RequireClientCertificate is set, but no local certificates were negotiated.  Is the server set to ask for client authorization?
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1428)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1413)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:188)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:646)
      at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
      ... 9 more
  Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.UntrustedURLConnectionIOException: RequireClientCertificate is set, but no local certificates were negotiated.  Is the server set to ask for client authorization?
      at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider$HttpsTokenOutInterceptor$1.establishTrust(HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider.java:121)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.TrustDecisionUtil.makeTrustDecision(TrustDecisionUtil.java:80)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1342)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1307)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1385)
      ... 14 more

  Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
      at $Proxy37.servicesCheck(Unknown Source)
      at lv.lattelecom.npais.sopa.IIndigentStatusService_BasicBinding_Client.main(IIndigentStatusService_BasicBinding_Client.java:170)
  Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.UntrustedURLConnectionIOException: UntrustedURLConnectionIOException invoking https://ws.yydats.org/services/StatusService.svc: RequireClientCertificate is set, but no local certificates were negotiated.  Is the server set to ask for client authorization?
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1428)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1413)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:188)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:646)
      at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
      at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
      at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
      ... 2 more
  Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.UntrustedURLConnectionIOException: RequireClientCertificate is set, but no local certificates were negotiated.  Is the server set to ask for client authorization?
      at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider$HttpsTokenOutInterceptor$1.establishTrust(HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider.java:121)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.TrustDecisionUtil.makeTrustDecision(TrustDecisionUtil.java:80)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1342)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1307)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
      at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
      at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1385)`enter code here`
```

Have anybody faced similar issue? Or maybe have any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the stack trace indicates, the SSL connection is refused by the server. Both your test clients are trying to establish a simple HTTPS connection (i.e. the client has a trustore where it keeps certificates that it will trust). However, the WS-Policy of your WSDL is clear on this matter:

```
<wsp:Policy>
  <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="true"/>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The clients will require a mutual HTTPS connection to authorize access to the web service (i.e. same as simple HTTPS + the client has its own keypair to identify himself to the server).
This probably works with other clients (SOAPUI) because they are more lenient and / or completely ignore the WS-Policy contraints.

So you have two options:

- You update one of your test scripts to setup a mutual HTTPS connection (I do not have code handy for this).
- You develop a simple test CXF client which does mutual HTTPS connection, there is a very nice sample project available from cxf-samples that does exactly what you need:
  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-2.4.4/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/

Comment: Thank you @ajeans I will tri this one.