# Apache CXF issue while using mutual SSL

Tags: java, soap, weblogic, cxf

I am using apache cxf for calling a web service from a weblogic server.The web service is SSL with mutual authentication based authorization.

There were some issues with the weblogic version 10.3 supporting the jdk version which i managed to resolve.

But now i am getting another error and not able to get much help on the internet

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.UntrustedURLConnectionIOException: RequireClientCertificate is set, but no local certificates were negotiated.  Is
the server set to ask for client authorization?
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider$HttpsTokenOutInterceptor$1.establishTrust(HttpsTokenInterceptorProvider.java:117)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.makeTrustDecision(HTTPConduit.java:1680)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1264)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1291)
        ... 43 more
```

I am using the configuration given here : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

Comment: Note : The error is wrong or something else is happening as the server is enabled to ask for client authentication

Comment: [Check Out this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403949/apache-cxf-client-issue-with-calling-ssl-service)

Comment: @Mayilarun i am already using the given example for 2 way mutual authentication but facing the issue

Comment: did you try to open the wsdl file through your browser first ?

Comment: Yes i am able to access the wsdl on the browser. I added the certificates and there were no warnings.

Comment: You should check the SSL debug logs. Enable it with VM arg -Djavax.net.debug=ssl

Answer (score 0):

we were getting this error also in these cases:

- wrong path to keystore
- referencing non existing alias in the keystore
- wrong certificate (cert for DEV environment used in TEST environment)

So I would suggest to double check the whole chain of settings to private certificate used to authenthicate against the ws.